# Output files with new file names in R

Tags: html, r, xml, rcurl

I am using R to get the XML files of these web pages. I have a csv file that has 6000 webpage links and I have a `for` loop that runs through each webpage link and gets the XML for each webpage link.

Now, I need to create 6000 separate XML file outputs. I need them to be labelled "1page" to "6000page".

Here is the code that I am using:

```
hf_file <- trial_href_file
hf_file$Href <- as.character(hf_file$Href)

for (i in 1:nrow(hf_file))
{
url2 = hf_file$Href[i]
h21 = GET(url2,user_agent("Gigabot/3.0    (http://www.gigablast.com/spider.html)"))%>% read_html()
data <- xmlParse(h21)
saved_html<- saveXML(data)
#write.csv(paste0(saved_html,i), file = "test.csv")
write.table(saved_html, file=paste0("C:/Users/keerthana.j/Documents/Car Database/Data", Sys.Time(), ".txt"))
#write.table(saved_html, "page_html.txt", sep=",", append = TRUE)
}
```

How do I write the output XML txt file with a new name for each webpage link that the `for` loop runs through?

Comment: What are you asking for ? You already paste a time into the name, how complicated is it  to add `,i` between the date and .txt ?

Comment: Also skip all the intermediate steps and just use download.file.

Comment: (a) are you an employee or authorized representative of gigablast? if not, using that user agent is skeezy at best (and much different ethically and legally than using a mozilla-ish one) (b) I see no code honoring the claim that you check `robots.txt` first (via http://www.gigablast.com/spider.html); do you? (c) lack of example URLs usually indicates either scraping a private, internal network (which is fine) or behavior that is less than ethical. (d) finally, Tensibai is right. if a numeric identifier is not sufficient, then did you do _any_ searches for generating unique ids in R?